# How can I inject Activity instance into my BroadcastReceiver with Android Annotation?

Tags: dependency-injection, android-annotations

I used to play with simple broadcast listeners into activity, there it is siple to do something like textView.setText("text"); But listener became quite large to stay inside and I carried it a separate class.
I like AA, I just want to continue manage views from current activity from my BroadcastReceiver that I have been separated. But when I do something like:

```
@EReceiver
public class WarningActivityStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @RootContext //or Bean
    WarningActivity activity;
```

I have an error:

```
Error:(25, 2) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.RootContext can only be used in a class annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean.
```

If I try to add @EBean above, then I have even worse:

```
Error:(27, 28) error: Something went wrong: Unexpected error in AndroidAnnotations 4.2.0!
You should check if there is already an issue about it on https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/search?q=java.lang.ClassCastException&type=Issues
If none exists, please open a new one with the following content and tell us if you can reproduce it or not. Don't forget to give us as much information as you can (like parts of your code in failure).
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because the `Context` of the `BroadcastReceiver` is the receiver itself, it is not related to any `Activity`. You can only inject the application `Context` here with the `@App` annotation.

**EDIT**:

You can annotate a method in your `Activity` with `@Receiver`, which will handle receiving `Intent`s and `BroadcastReceiver` registration / deregistration:

```
@EActivity
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Receiver(actions = "org.androidannotations.ACTION_1")
  protected void onAction1() {
    // Will be called when an org.androidannotations.ACTION_1 intent is sent.
  }

}
```

Or you can create a normal `BroadcastReceiver`, and send events from its `onReceive` method to the `Activity` via an event bus, or a `LocalBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thank you. But how to interact with UI in this case? Before using AA I used to create a constructor with my WarningActivity. In activity it looks like  `private BroadcastReceiver stateReceiver = new WarningActivityStateListener(this);`, and in receiver it was as `public WarningActivityStateListener(WarningActivity activity) {
  this.activity = activity;
 }` - so I could use the Activity to change views. Please advise how to replace it with the AA.

Comment: I think IntentBuilder of App may help, but don't know how )